# how to use scale and dist with a dataset with column name

Tags: r

Trying to scale a dataset with 9 variables to be prepared for clustering. My data has headers (column names). It keeps giving me this response.
I have already excluded the rownames in the dataset

Warning message:
In dist(DF, method = "euclidean") : NAs introduced by coercion

> View(DF)
>   Error in View : cannot coerce class ""dist"" to a data.frame

Answer (score 1):

First of a comment to your question-style: add a snippet of data and take more time explaining the problem, and what you have tried already!

The error `NAs introduced by coercion` normally occurs, when conversion between datatypes failed (as the name suggests). Check your column for non-numeric elements (are letters included somewhere? Wrong Decimals?).

This great blog explains nicely where and why the problems occur and how to fix it! http://r-bio.github.io/02-data-frames/.